# How to fix Gradle Sync errors setting up new React-Native Project for Android and iOS

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

I am trying to start using React-Native for some of my mobile development.
Most of it seems very straight forward from the React-Native Docs on Github but I cant get projects to build in Android Studio.

When I try importing the project by navigating to the ProjectName/android/app and selecting import I get this when the project tries to build.

```
SDK Location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

[SDK location not found screenhsot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP9ji.png)

I have retyped deleted and recreated the local.properties file a few times to see if that helped. It didn't. It looks like this.

[local.properties screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdIqV.png)

I learned about VIM and how to use it a little in an effort to figure out what this whole "ANDROID_HOME" environment variable was about.

I edited my .bashrc and .bash_profile to look like this using VIM. These files are in my User Folder as far as I understand. They both look exactly like this now.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Carl/Library/Android/sdk
```

I can run the projects in the emulator fine in iOS and Android. I can edit js files and get them to work just like I want. I seem to be able to do stuff in Xcode too. What I cant do is work with Java for trying to build Native Modules for Android since projects wont build.

Lastly to be thorough: 
Android Studio 1.5.1
React-Native 0.18.1
OS X El Capitan

Also the sdk's and build tools are all in line as far as I can tell.

If anyone has any knowledge on how to fix this Gradle Sync error with Android Studio and React Native I would greatly appreciate the help! Until I do I cant work with Native Modules...

Comment: Have you restarted your terminal window after setting the environment variable?

Comment: Yes I have shut down the terminal and restarted it and checked that the environment variables remained as expected. Also did some whole machine restarts and reinstalled android studio.

Comment: Was your sdk downloaded with homebrew? If so, try `brew info android` and check to see if you have the right Android-SDK path

Comment: I use the default Android Studio SDK Manager for downloading the sdks's When i run    `brew info android`  i get the below comment

Comment: `android-sdk: stable 24.4.1 (bottled)
Android API libraries and developer tools
https://developer.android.com/index.html
Conflicts with: android-platform-tools
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
==> Caveats
Now run the 'android' tool to install the actual SDK stuff.

The Android-SDK is available at /usr/local/opt/android-sdk

You may need to add the following to your .bashrc:
  export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`

Answer (score 7):

This was a learning experience. When opening a project in Android Studio, open at the `ProjectName/android/` folder not the `ProjectName/android/app/` folder.

If I hadn't spent the last year doing iOS in Xcode this would have likely never happened. Noob mistake. Opening at the `/android/` folder fixed all my problems.